# Derivative of method with respect to instance variables

Tags: python, lambda

This is a problem I have in back propagation (neural networks).
I have a method that evaluated the costs and the weights are instance variables of the same class. I want to calculate the derivative with respect of these weights (they can be many).
How do I do that in an "elegant" way? The weights are in an dictionary.
Can I do this outside the function, or do I need to change it?

An example:

```
class T(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.coff = {'a':2, 'b':3}

    def dfuna(self, x, y , a):
        self.coff['a'] = a   #one problem is here
        return self.fun(x,y)

    def dfunb(self, x, y , b):
        self.coff['b'] = b   #same here
        return self.fun(x,y)

    def fun(self, x, y):
        a, b = self.coff['a'], self.coff['b']
        return a*x**2 + b*y**2

T = T()
print(T.fun(1,1))

def derivative(f, x, h = 1e-6):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / (2 * h)

x,y = 1,2
f = lambda dx : T.fun(dx,y)
print(derivative(f,x))

a = 2
g = lambda da : T.dfuna(x,y,da)
print(derivative(g,a))

b = 3
g = lambda db : T.dfunb(x,y,db)
print(derivative(g,b))
```

How would I in this example calculate the derivatives of `T.fun()` with respect to 'a' and 'b'?
The "extra" functions `dfuna()` and `dfunb()` are in this example added by me.
Problem is that there can be many instance variables.

Comment: I'd love to help you, what are you exactly looking for ? To me, saying `How would I in this example calculate the derivatives of T.fun() with respect to 'a' and 'b'?, you're asking for a mathematical question, a formulae. Do you wish to have your `derivative` function inside `T()` class ?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I want to taket the derivatives of `T.fun()` but with respect of 'a' and 'b'. The problem is that I can't "reach" them with a lambda function, the way I can with x and y.

Comment: I added more code to try to illustrate the problem.

Comment: do you need to implement the derivative function yourself (e.g. as part of an assignment), or could you use existing libraries? Because there's theano (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html) and autograd (https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md), for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I guess in "reality" you never need to calculate the derivatives yourself. This is just me trying to check my own implementation of back propagation manually.